# Hibernate how to return Json value?

Tags: spring, hibernate

Hi I have this controller method that returns a list of customers and displays it using a model.

```
@Controller
public class timesheetController 
{
    @Autowired
    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    @GetMapping("/getCustomers")
    public String getCustomers(Model view)
    {
        //get customers from dao
        List<Customer> results = customerDAO.getCustomers(); 

        //add the customers to the model
        view.addAttribute("customers", results);

        return "list-customers";
    }   
}
```

However I would like to return the list as a json to get an output like

```
{
    "Customer_Code": T77A,
    "Customer_Name": CustomerName1
},
{
    "Customer_Code": T77B,
    "Customer_Name": CustomerName2
}
```

I tried just returning the list as follows

```
@Controller
public class timesheetController 
{
    @Autowired
    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    @GetMapping("/getCustomers")
    public List<Customer> getCustomers()
    {
        //get customers from dao
        List<Customer> results = customerDAO.getCustomers(); 

        return results;
    }   
}
```

but then I get this error as it seems to be expecting a view. How can I return the desired json output?
[image]

Comment: Your method has to return ResponseEntity<CustomerDao> it will automatically send in json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you are trying to call getCustomers.jsp. What you want, instead, is not a JSP page but a JSON response. So you should make an AJAX call (by using JQuery or other framework or native JS)
So what I would do is change your Controller class in this way:

```
@Controller
public class timesheetController 
{
    @Autowired
    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    @GetMapping("/getCustomers", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> getCustomers()
    {
        List<Customer> payload = customerDAO.getCustomers(); 
        return ResponseEntity
        .ok()
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        .body(payload);
    }   
}
```

Then I would make the JSON call (I'm using JQuery in this example):

```
var baseUrl = YOUR_WEB_APP_CONTEXT/getCustomers;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: baseUrl,
    success: function(data) {
        //All OK.. you should have the JSON response
    },
    error: function() {
        //Something was wrong; you chould check
    }               
});
```